# Android: How to scale the width of the pen stroke

Tags: android, pdf, stroke, pen

Probably this not related directly to Android. I have an image which have drawn with Pen tool of stroke 4px. If I have to draw it back to a pdf or other document and their size of the pages are different to the image, how do I scale stroke from image to pdf (or other document) size so it can get the drawing path the same porportion

Comment: Use a _real_ unit, like points.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not new and Android framework expects you to [use some technics](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

The key thing in your case - density-independent pixel (dp).